# Ubuntu 22.04 VirtualBox occasionally becomes unresponsive and I have to Reset

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04, boinc

I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed on a windows 10 machine using VirtualBox.  Occassionally it will freeze (once while using it but mostly I find it frozen after walking away from the PC when I return.

Has anyone suggestions on where to look for logs or how to troubleshoot (or even better solve) this issue?

**Update 1** error found after running journalctl:

```
kernel: [Firmware Bug]: TSC doesn't count with P0 frequency!
kernel: APIC calibration not consistent with PM-Timer: 108ms instead of 100ms

kernel: .... node  #0, CPUs:      #1
kernel: TSC synchronization [CPU#0 -> CPU#1]:
kernel: Measured 19079 cycles TSC warp between CPUs, turning off TSC clock.
kernel: tsc: Marking TSC unstable due to check_tsc_sync_source failed
kernel:  #2 #3 #4 #5
kernel: smp: Brought up 1 node, 6 CPUs
```

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community**. To clarify, does the VM freeze or does the host machine freeze? As for some tools to start troubleshooting, try using the `dmesg` (or `journalctl` since you're running a systemd-based OS) command to see if there are any warnings/errors getting generated.

Comment: Thanks for checking!  The VM freezes.

when running journalctl I found this:

Comment: Looks like you're missing the `journalctl` output in your comment. Probably best to go ahead and add it directly to your question.

Comment: Thanks, added the comment.

Comment: From your `journalctl` output, chatter on the web suggests that this may be a BIOS issue on the host machine (the short search suggests an older Ryzen issue... not sure if that's relevant in your case). You might want to limit your virtual instance of Ubuntu to a single CPU and see if this issue still occurs.